# stopwatch on VB2012 windows forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to program a stopwatch with the format hh:mm:ss.
I have a timer that start's when you click the start button and stops when you click the stop button.
I have a label that when it starts it has the text 00:00:00
the timer has and interval of 1000 so that it updates the label every second, but when i try adding 00:00:00 + 00:00:01 i get a error, i tried parse but i failed miserably

my code for the updating of the label:

```
Dim total As Date
Dim segundo As Date
Dim actual As Date

actual = DateTime.Parse(Label22.Text)
segundo = DateTime.Parse("00:00:01")
total = actual + segundo

Label22.Text = total.ToShortTimeString
```

Then buttons have:

```
Timer2.Start()
```

and

```
Timer2.Stop()
```

Thanks for helping,

The ideia is that when you press start then stop then again start it will continue from where it stopped

Bruno

Comment: What errors do you receive and what line does it take you to? (Errors are not just random text - they have a meaning that helps to fix the problem.)

Comment: The error isnt while compiling, it compiles then when i click start i get: A conversão da cadeia "24-07-201324-07-2013 00:00:01" para o tipo 'Date' não é válida.  Translation: <b>The conversion of the chain "24-07-201324-07-2013 00:00:01" to the type 'Date' isn't valid.</b>            but i don't understand where that chain comes from :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find it much easier just to use `AddSeconds(1)`

```
Dim total As Date
'Dim segundo As Date
Dim actual As Date

actual = DateTime.Parse("00:00:00")
    'or actual = DateTime.Parse(Label22.Text)

'Debug.Print(actual)
'segundo = DateTime.Parse("00:00:01")
total = actual.AddSeconds(1)

Debug.Print(total.ToLongTimeString)
    'or Label22.Text = total.ToLongTimeString
```

`segundo` is no longer needed and I'm using `ToLongTimeString` to show the seconds.

[AddSeconds :MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds.aspx)